# minimizing memory use in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I was working on a problem in codeforces and I have no problems in the functionality of the code but the code exceeds the memory usage. Can someone explain how to improve this? How to learn about memory management in general while programming because I didn't find anything related to that. Here's my code :

**Summary of the problem:** You are given 6 input numbers, the first 5 numbers should be multiplied each by another integer and the summation of them after multiplication is the **sixth** integer in the input. You should find all the combinations of the numbers the can be multiplied by each value in the input to seek the summation. the output is basically the sum of the integers chosen for each number in the input to be multiplied by.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

#ifndef MAX
#define MAX 100
#endif

using namespace std;

void storeAndFilter(vector <int> &arr,int chosenNumConst, int mypasha);
void print(vector<int> &v);
int printsum(vector<int> &v);


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //array of input options
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, pasha;
    cin >> a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> a4 >> a5 >> pasha;

    //declarations of vectors
    vector<int> arrStrA1;
    vector<int> arrStrA2;
    vector<int> arrStrA3;
    vector<int> arrStrA4;
    vector<int> arrStrA5;

    //sorting and filtering the vectors
    storeAndFilter(arrStrA1,a1,pasha);
    storeAndFilter(arrStrA2,a2,pasha);
    storeAndFilter(arrStrA3,a3,pasha);
    storeAndFilter(arrStrA4,a4,pasha);
    storeAndFilter(arrStrA5,a5,pasha);

    //cout<<"All Posibilities valid (Minimized by removing values < pasha) : "<<endl;
    // print (arrStrA1);
    // print (arrStrA2);
    // print (arrStrA3);
    // print (arrStrA4);
    // print (arrStrA5);

    //scores vectors
    vector<int> resultsA1;
    vector<int> resultsA2;
    vector<int> resultsA3;
    vector<int> resultsA4;
    vector<int> resultsA5;


    int i,j,k,l,m;
    for (i=0; i < (int)arrStrA1.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (j=0; j < (int)arrStrA2.size(); ++j)
        {
            for (k=0; k < (int)arrStrA3.size(); ++k)
            {
                for (l=0; l < (int)arrStrA4.size(); ++l)
                {
                    for (m=0; m < (int)arrStrA5.size(); ++m)
                    {
                        if(arrStrA1.at(i)+arrStrA2.at(j)+arrStrA3.at(k)+arrStrA4.at(l)+arrStrA5.at(m)==pasha)
                        { 

                            resultsA1.push_back(arrStrA1.at(i));
                            resultsA2.push_back(arrStrA2.at(j));
                            resultsA3.push_back(arrStrA3.at(k));
                            resultsA4.push_back(arrStrA4.at(l));
                            resultsA5.push_back(arrStrA5.at(m));


                        }

                    }   
                }   
            }   
        }
    }



    //divise each term by the card value
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)resultsA1.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (a1==0)
            resultsA1.at(i) /= 1;
        else
            resultsA1.at(i) /= a1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)resultsA2.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (a2==0)
            resultsA2.at(i) /= 1;
        else
            resultsA2.at(i) /= a2;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)resultsA3.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(a3==0)
            resultsA3.at(i) /= 1;
        else
            resultsA3.at(i) /= a3;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)resultsA4.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (a4==0)
            resultsA4.at(i) /= 1;
        else        
            resultsA4.at(i) /= a4;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)resultsA5.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(a5==0)
            resultsA5.at(i) /= 1;
        else
            resultsA5.at(i) /= a5;
    }

    //Uncomment to show the table list after division
    // print(resultsA1);
    // print(resultsA2);
    // print(resultsA3);
    // print(resultsA4);
    // print(resultsA5);

    int scra1=printsum(resultsA1);
    int scra2=printsum(resultsA2);
    int scra3=printsum(resultsA3);
    int scra4=printsum(resultsA4);
    int scra5=printsum(resultsA5);

    cout << scra1 <<" "<< scra2 <<" "<< scra3 <<" "<<scra4 <<" "<< scra5 <<endl;


    return 0;
}


void print(vector<int> &v)
{
    int size = v.size();
    cout<<"========================"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout<<v.at(i)<<endl;
    cout<<"========================"<<endl;

}

int printsum(vector<int> &v)
{
    int sum =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)v.size(); ++i)
        sum += v.at(i);
    return sum;
}

void storeAndFilter(vector <int> &arr,int chosenNumConst, int mypasha)
{
    arr.reserve(10);
    int i=0;

    for (; i <= MAX; ++i)
    {
        arr.push_back(i*chosenNumConst);
        if (arr.at(i)>mypasha)  
            break;
    }

    arr.resize(i);
}
```

Some stuff that I thought about:

- Arrays instead of Vectors maybe better
- The nested for loops may be the one that is taking too much memory

But to be clear, the nested for loops doesn't make too much calculations, they find all the combinations of 5 numbers '5 loops' to sum to a specific value. Filtering before entering the loop is applied so maybe the nested loop isn't the issue. 
Max memory constrain in the problem is: **256 MB**

Comment: Memory usage exceeded or the size of the source code?

Comment: Without reserve on your result vectors they could be using double or even three times the necessary memory

Comment: In the nested loop in `main()`, every vector is going to have `100^5`  (i.e. `10^10`) elements pushed to it.   [Note:  I'm using `^` to represent exponentiation, not bitshifting].   Assuming an `int` is two bytes, each vector requires 20 GB of storage.   For a 4-byte `int` (which is common in practice) that grows to 40GB.   There are five of those arrays, so the memory required is 100GB (minimum) or 200GB (more likely) just for those five arrays.

Comment: @OP Advice -- These online coding / quiz sites are notorious for asking questions that have naive answers that only work for small input.  Your answer is naive in both time complexity and space complexity.  The goal of these questions is to see if you can come up a different algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: are negative values allowed for the input? for the factors?

Comment: @Thomas no, positive only

Answer (score 0):

You can use much less memory by not using all those vectors. You can just write your code like this:

```
    // make sure we handle zero properly
    auto end = [&](int num){
        return num == 0 ? num : pasha/num;
    };

    for (auto i=0, end_i = end(a1); i <= end_i; ++i)
    {
        for (auto j=0, end_j = end(a2); j <= end_j; ++j)
        {
            for (auto k=0, end_k = end(a3); k <= end_k; ++k)
            {
                for (auto l=0, end_l = end(a4); l <= end_l; ++l)
                {
                    for (auto m=0, end_m = end(a5); m <= end_m; ++m)
                    {
                        if(a1*i+a2*j+a3*k+a4*l+a5*m==pasha)
                        { 
                            std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << " " << l << " " << m << "\n";
                        }
                    }   
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
```

and it outputs all the valid results. For Example for the input `0 2 3 4 5 6` it produces

```
0 0 2 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 3 0 0 0
```

See working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5f0035ac445ec9b)